# ember Observe isSaving

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, observers

Have someone tried to observe isSaving attribute with Ember 1.0.0, which just releases last week.  It seems does not work.

Here is the code:

```
var tempObject= HubStar.Mega.createRecord({
});

tempObject.addObserver('isSaving', function() {
        if (mega.get('isSaving')) {
   console.log('isSaving');
        }
        else {
      }
          console.log('isSaved');
    });

App.store.save();
```

I know there is some changes, but how I can observe the object with the new Ember version?
Is it there another way to do that?

Comment: What version of ember-data are you using?

Comment: The latest one, Ember.js 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the transition guide https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md you could try something like:

```
this.store.createRecord('mega')
tempObject.one('isSaving', function(){ ... });

this.store.save();
```

Accessing the `Store` and creating/finding records has also changed.
Although am not 100% sure those event still exist or will continue to exist in favour of promises?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, Colymba. I have tried your method, but it does not work.

However, from the transition guide, I found another solution. Something like this:
        mega.save().then(function() {
            // work with saved person
            // newly created records are guaranteed to have IDs assigned
        }, function() {
            // work with person that failed to save
        });

The interesting thing is, when a record is saved, it runs the second function(), but not the first one. Is something wrong I made?